# Possessive S after author name

Tags: possessives, attributive-nouns

There's a book that analyses a bunch of stories by Joseph Conrad, and I'm wondering what's the correct title:

1. An analysis of Joseph Conrad's stories
2. An analysis of Joseph Conrad stories

I would go for 1 with the possessive S, but someone mentioned that 2 works because 1 implies an analysis of *all* his stories.

What would be the preferred option here?

Thanks!

Comment: I've voted to close this because it is explicitly soliciting mere personal opinion about preferences rather than seeking an answer backed by fact and citations instead of opinions.

Comment: I am trying to understand which one is the correct one here, as I'm not sure at all

Comment: It would be tricky, but perhaps not completely impossible, to come up with a scenario in which using one or the other of an attributive noun (so, like *Conrad tales*) and a possessive noun (so, like *Conrad’s tales*) would be clearly wrong and the other clearly right. For example, are these stories that other people have written about Joseph Conrad, or are these stories which Joseph Conrad himself wrote? Might anyone be confused? Consider if, instead of tales about or by Conrad, it were Shakespeare plays or [Shakespeare movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_in_Love) being analysed.

Comment: Neither is incorrect. Your friend is right that [1] does point in the direction of completeness, but language is often used hyperbolically (What? You missed “Freya of the Seven Isles”?) without intent to deceive and without causing chagrin. [1] is less clinical, and I'd say register is the larger factor here (though hardly compelling).

Comment: They are both fine. Without context, there is no implication that all stories are involved in (1). cf. *Do you like Bob’s shoes?* In any case, (1) is more natural.

Comment: Also consider the meaning of "An analysis of Sherlock Holmes stories".

Comment: How could that not depend entirely on the context?

Answer (score -3):

Both options can be grammatically correct, but they convey slightly different meanings:

1. "An Analysis of Joseph Conrad's Stories" implies that the book analyzes a specific set of stories by Joseph Conrad, likely multiple stories but not necessarily all of them.
2. "An Analysis of Joseph Conrad Stories" is grammatically correct, but it could be interpreted as a broader analysis that encompasses all of Conrad's stories. However, it's a bit less precise than the first option because it doesn't explicitly indicate possession or specify which stories are being analyzed.

Given the context and intention to analyze a bunch of stories by Joseph Conrad, option 1 ("An Analysis of Joseph Conrad's Stories") would be the preferred choice as it accurately communicates the scope of the analysis without necessarily implying that it covers every single one of his stories.

Comment: That's not really how nouns work in English. "Joseph Conrad stories" is an indefinite phrase and could mean some or all, but doesn't imply all, any more than "an analysis of science fiction stories" would. Using 's+plural commonly implies there is a predefined group of objects under consideration and you're asking about all of them - "Did you bring Jane's books?" may mean "Did you bring all of the books you have, or all of her books, or all of the relevant books, etc?" not "Did you bring one of Jane's books?"